# stopping onclick event handler

Tags: javascript, event-handling, dom-events

I have some working code that I'm now using in slightly different context. The working part is that I use  objects onclick event to bring up a form to send an e-mail. When this in an HTML page, it works fine. I would have a lot of buttons that look like this:

```
<button id="mail-c1" onclick="initMailFormButton(this.id, 'someone','somedomain.com','a subject')">Someone's Name</button>
```

The entire form is created in javascript and has its own submit and cancel buttons but is within the button element. In order to be able to enter data into the form, I need to kill the onclick event then restore it after I've submitted or cancelled the e-mail. The onclick handler starts out with:

```
function initMailFormButton(mailId, eName, eDomain, eSubject) {
    myFormLocation = document.getElementById(mailId);
    stopFormClick(myFormLocation);
```

where the stopFormClick function is:

```
function stopFormClick(myFormLocation) {
    saveOnclick = myFormLocation.onclick;
    myFormLocation.onclick = null;
}
```

This has the bug that it doesn't handle someone opening multiple forms at once, but that's not my immediate concern. I'll fix it outside of this discussion.

The submit and cancel buttons in the generated form both restore the onclick event handler so you can open and close the form multiple times quite happily.

My new case is that I'm generating HTML page from a database. I'm using HTML datasets to store the previously hard-coded information like so:

```
    emailButton.setAttribute("data-mailname",   emailName);
    emailButton.setAttribute("data-maildomain", emailDomain);
    emailButton.addEventListener("click", function() { initMailFormButton(this.id, this.dataset.mailname, this.dataset.maildomain, ""); }, false);
```

The information being retrieved is correct and the form appears in the correct location. However, I can't enter information because the original onclick handler kicks in when I click in the first form field and generates another form...

The only clue I have is that when I look at the value of the onclick event being saved in the static HTML pages, it has the expected value but it is null in the generated pages. I find this confusing because I am passing the (unique) element id to the routine so it should be getting to the correct element.

Can anyone help me on this one. Meanwhile, I'll fix the event handler bug I mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

OK. So it's that there is a difference between click and onclick. The onclick event handler wasn't set so it is null. I changed setting the click event listener to setting the onclick attribute as:

```
    emailButton.onclick = 
        function() { initMailFormButton(this.id, this.dataset.mailname, this.dataset.maildomain, ""); };
```

and everything works nicely.

To handle the limitation I'd noted earlier, I made the saveOnclick variable into an associative array keyed by the button id. Now people can have as many buttons clicked as they want - although wanting to have more than one is probably rare.